# Render a raster with hue values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis

I have a single-band raster (a GeoTIFF) with hue values in the band. I'd like to render it, preferably in QGIS but another open-source GIS would be acceptable as well. The saturation and value should be held constant at 255.

Answer (score 3):

If the values you want to render are in the band then choosing any colour ramp will work. When creating manually a color ramp the saturation value is fixed by default at 255.